# Registration in spring security not using inMemoryAuth. or jdbcAuth

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, security, spring-security

So I am using spring security, and since this is only my home server(which will use like 5-10 people) I am storing all user data in text file(all information is encrypted). Before I used spring-security I tried to write my one kind of security API, but it didn't work well. The only thing I need is to add new users in runtime, but it seems that it is impossible. Do you have any idea how to do this in a way where I don't have to change much?

Comment: If what you want is to avoid using a database server running on your machine, why don't you use H2 or any of the embedded databases, which stores your whole database on a local file

Comment: I would like to use mysql but i am currently on linux and can use it for some reason...

Comment: Using an embedded database seems to me like it's your best bet, plus; if you are building your application with abstraction in mind - you will be able to effortlessly switch to MySQL later on